# how to keep button disable any editText Empty?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext, android-textwatcher

how to keep button disable any editText Empty ?

i've try with `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'`:

```
txtEmailOrNoPhone.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            if (text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                buttonLogin.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                txtPassword.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
                    buttonLogin.isEnabled = text.toString().isNotEmpty()
                }
            }
        }
```

but, not work.

because, if i run app (button enable). if i type and delete all (button disable). so, i must type first and delete to (button disable)

i want :
if start app

Comment: The question is not really clear, please try explaining better your problem, maybe posting some screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code inside the `doOnTextChanged` is not triggered until you type something, your initial state of disabling the button will not work.

For that, just set the button disabled initially in the xml

`android:enabled="false"`